# .net mono port to Linux can't see dep file

Tags: c#, linux, dll, mono

I am porting .NET app to Linux with help of Mono, and i run into problem with one DLL (HTML to PDF conversion) that uses a dep file. When running app it pulls an error that this dependency file can't be seen.
Is there any solutions for this situation?

Comment: Show your source code, show the error text

Comment: An exception stack trace and the code surrounding that exception would be needed to help